# Setting secure cookie through HTTPS with XHR on HTTP localhost

Tags: reactjs, cookies, setcookie

I'm running a CRA React app on localhost:3000, the app uses axios and the app makes the following API call to `https://api-local.domain.io:3010/xxx/authorize` that responds with a header:

```
set-cookie: gd_resource=XXX; Domain=.domain.io; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 23 Jun 2022 16:08:05 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None
```

This cookie is configured so that it will be sent to any request to a subdomain of `domain.io` for any API calls. So it has to be `Secure`.

But I can see that it is not sent when an API call is sent to `https://project-dev.domain.io/yyy`.

I don't understand why, is it because I'm running the app on HTTP?

I tried running it on `http://editor-local.domain.io:3000` changing my `/etc/hosts` file but it doesn't change anything.

I've tried running the app on `https://localhost:3000` using mkcert but Chrome said the certificate is invalid although my keychain seems to be ok with it.

---

**EDIT**

I managed to have my app running on `https://editor-local.domain.io:3000` with mkcert but it does not change a thing: the cookie is still not sent with the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the thing: the parameter `withCredentials: true` of axios requests has 2 functions:

- it tells axios to send available cookies;
- it also tells the browser to save cookies that are returned in the `set-cookie` header of the response.

So my request to `https://api-local.domain.io:3010/xxx/authorize` must be made with `withCredentials: true`.